# javascript change output format of string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to produce an output from a string like this:

```
str = "1.000;74.85;10.000;62.13;9999;74.85;15000";
```

To:

```
1-10 : 74.85
10-9999 : 62.13
9999-15000 : 74.85
```

So that the indexes end up like this:
    1-3 : 2
    3-5 : 4
    5-7 : 6

And the odd indexes get converted to integers

I wrote some script but the result is not expected and I think that it is too much code. There is probably some other shorter way.

My code:

```
    var str = "1.000;74.85;10.000;62.13;9999;74.85;15000";
    var delimiter = ';';

    function splitString(stringToSplit, separator) {
        return stringToSplit.split(separator);
    }

    var arr = splitString(str, delimiter);
    var oddElement = [];
    var evenElement = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if ((i % 2) === 0) {
            oddElement.push(parseInt(arr[i]))
        } else if ((i % 2) != 0) {
            evenElement.push(arr[i]);
        }

    }

    function duplicateElements(array, times) { 
        return array.slice(1,-1).reduce((res, current) => {
            return res.concat(Array(times).fill(current));
        }, []);

    }

    oddElement = duplicateElements(oddElement, 2);
    oddElement.unshift(parseInt(arr[0]));
    oddElement.push(parseInt(arr[arr.length - 1]));
    temp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < oddElement.length; i ++) {
        temp.push(oddElement[i] + '-' + oddElement[++i]);
    }


   evenElement.forEach(function(el) {
        for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            console.log(temp[i] + ":" + el);
        }       
    })

   console.log(temp);
   console.log(evenElement);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = "1.000;74.85;10.000;62.13;9999;74.85;15000";
var arr = str.split(';');
var len = arr.length;
var data = [];
for (i = 1; i < arr.length - 1; i+=2) {
  data.push(arr[i - 1] + '-' + arr[i + 1] + ' : ' + arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a single loop and append your answer to a string one line at a time.  An easy way to design this type of logic is to look at your desired result by index in the split array:

```
parseInt(splitStr[1]) + "-" + parseInt(splitStr[3]) + " : " + splitStr[2]
```

Then just figure out how to get that same result on each iteration of the loop:

```js
str = "1.000;74.85;10.000;62.13;9999;74.85;15000"; 

splitStr = str.split(";");

outputStr = "";

for (let i = 0 ;  i < splitStr.length - 2 ; i += 2) {
    outputStr += parseInt(splitStr[i]) + "-" + parseInt(splitStr[i + 2]) + " : " + splitStr[i + 1] + "\n";
}

console.log(outputStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a functional way to do it:

1. Split
2. Parse each value
3. create objects containing start(s), end(e) and value(v) for each range
4. **(optional)** map over objects to make strings

```js
const str = "1.000;74.85;10.000;62.13;9999;74.85;15000";

function format1(s, d = ';') {
  return s
    .split(d)
    .map(n => parseFloat(n))
    .reduce((r, n, i, a) => {
      if (i > 1 && i % 2 === 0)
        r.push({
          s: a[i - 2],
          v: a[i - 1],
          e: n
        });
      return r;
    }, []);
}

const formatted1 = format1(str);
const formatted2 = formatted1.map(({
  s,
  v,
  e
}) => `${s}-${e} : ${v}`);
console.log(formatted1);
console.log(formatted2);
```